# R reverse some rows in a matrix

Tags: r, reverse

I have a 60 column matrix, and I want to reverse the some of its rows.
I came across the following two ways to do this:

```
#rtr is an integer vectors with the indices of the rows I want to reverse
matrix[rtr,]<-matrix[rtr,(ncol(matrix):1]
```

and

```
matrix[rtr,]<-rev(mat[rtr,])
```

Are these two implementations expected to produce the same result, or
are there some differences between them?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a pretty easy thing to test

```
mm <- matrix(1:(6*7), ncol=6)
m2 <- m1 <- mm

rtr<-c(1,6,7)
m1[rtr,]<-m1[rtr, ncol(m1):1]

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]   36   29   22   15    8    1
# [2,]    2    9   16   23   30   37
# [3,]    3   10   17   24   31   38
# [4,]    4   11   18   25   32   39
# [5,]    5   12   19   26   33   40
# [6,]   41   34   27   20   13    6
# [7,]   42   35   28   21   14    7

m2[rtr,]<-rev(m2[rtr,])

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]   42   35   28   21   14    7
# [2,]    2    9   16   23   30   37
# [3,]    3   10   17   24   31   38
# [4,]    4   11   18   25   32   39
# [5,]    5   12   19   26   33   40
# [6,]   41   34   27   20   13    6
# [7,]   36   29   22   15    8    1
```

We can see they produce different output. The latter changes the order of the rows as well rather than just reversing them "in place"